# To display clicked list-item value in mat-nav-list component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using `<mat-nav-list>` component to display the navigation bar and also the `header(i,e  mat-toolbar)`  to display the clicked `list-items(ex Home 1)` like this:

[image]

- Now i  want to display the selected /clicked `list -item(ex Home 2)` on the header.
- Means on clicking `Home 2` , `Home 2` should display on the `header.`

Stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/selection-list-activelinks-cm9csg?file=app/selection-list/selection-list.component.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could just have used `*ngFor` to loop through the `listItems`

Use a `selectedItem` property and set in on the `click` of the menu-item:

```
export class SelectionListComponent {

  selectedItem = '';

  listItems = [
    { linkTitle: 'Home 1', link: '/home-a' },
    { linkTitle: 'Home 2', link: '/home-b' },
    { linkTitle: 'Home 3', link: '/home-c' },
    { linkTitle: 'Home 4', link: '/home-d' },
    { linkTitle: 'Home 5', link: '/home-e' },
  ];

  handleClick(selectedItem) {
    this.selectedItem = selectedItem.linkTitle;
  }

}
```

Now, to get the Nav Link active, you'll just have to define the routes and then apply the `routerLinkActive` directive and give it the name of the class you want to apply to it when it's active.

In template:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">{{ selectedItem }}</mat-toolbar>

<mat-nav-list>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of listItems" (click)="handleClick(item)">
        <mat-icon  matListIcon>home</mat-icon>
        <a 
          [routerLink]="item.link" 
          routerLinkActive="active" 
          matLine>
          {{item.linkTitle}}
        </a>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-nav-list>
```

In the css, you'll have to define the active class:

```
.active {
  color: #673AB7;
  font-weight: bold!important;
}
```

And then in your AppModule:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'home-a', component : SelectionListComponent },
      { path: 'home-b', component : SelectionListComponent },
      { path: 'home-c', component : SelectionListComponent },
      { path: 'home-d', component : SelectionListComponent },
      { path: '**', component: SelectionListComponent }
    ])
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[**Updated StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/selection-list-kqiy3p?file=app%2Fselection-list%2Fselection-list.component.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but by default it should not display anything,Only on click it should display.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I don't want to pass `list-items` as array, Because i am using `list-items` as **menu**. Each `list-item` as separate `routing-link`.

Comment: Actually i am highlighting the `background-color` and `text-color` on-clicking the `list-item` . See this link : **https://stackblitz.com/edit/selection-list-activelinks-cm9csg?file=app/selection-list/selection-list.component.html**

Comment: Update link is working fine, but on refreshing the page it is disappearing.

Comment: Of course, it will disappear. When you refresh the page, essentially the whole Single Page Application reinitializes. And that's what resets the state of the application. This is an expected behavior.

Comment: In this link : **https://stackblitz.com/edit/selection-list-activelinks-cm9csg?file=app/selection-list/selection-list.component.html** The router-link (i,e Home 2/3/4) is highlighted even on refresh. Is it possible to do like this?

Comment: Sure. It's possible. You'll just have to define the routes and then apply the `routerLinkActive` directive and give it the name of the class you want to apply to it when it's active. Let me update the answer for you.

Comment: Okay,Thanks for the responding again..:)

Answer (score 2):

**Demo Code :** https://stackblitz.com/edit/selection-list-activelinks-example?file=app/selection-list/selection-list.component.ts

**Approach :** Take a member variable for showing in header, 
and use click event as `(click)="selected='Home 1'"` on every `mat-list-item`. So that on every click change this selected variable accordingly.

```
 <mat-toolbar color="primary"> {{selected}}</mat-toolbar>
<mat-nav-list>
    <mat-list-item [routerLink]="['/home1']" 
   (click)="selected='Home 1'" 
   [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        <mat-icon [class.active]="selected" matListIcon>home</mat-icon>
        <a matLine>Home 1</a>
    </mat-list-item>

    <mat-list-item [routerLink]="['/home2']" 
    (click)="selected='Home 2'"
    [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        <mat-icon matListIcon>home</mat-icon>
        <a matLine>Home 2</a>
    </mat-list-item>
<mat-nav-list>
```

Comment: Such assignments shouldn't be directly placed in the template. A function should be created instead and called from the template. That way its easier to debug and Unit Test.

Comment: @SiddAjmera thank you for the information, for small assignments i do directly in the code, but yes debugging and unit test is much easier if somewhat small to small logics are kept in .ts file. I will keep this in mind now onwards.